# Send html form to node.js, process data and give that data to another page

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have an html form with some checkboxes and I want the node.js server to process the client input using information stored in a .json file and send the results back to the client to a different page.

It checks whether a recipe (many stored in the .json file) can be made, based on the ingredients that are available (checked in the form).

Up until now, I was able to search around and program this website to the point that I can send the form, process it (very shortened code below) and get the result back, but I don't know what to do with it, it is just displayed in the page as pure .json (that is what I'm sending, it is normal).

The html part:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Recipes</title>
</head>
<body class="container">
    <main>
        <form action="/search_result" method="post">
            <input type="checkbox" name="beef_roast"> Beef
            <input type="checkbox" name="beef_roast"> Pork
            <input type="checkbox" name="beef_roast"> Fish
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search recipe</button>
        </form>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

The node.js part

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/search_result', function(req, res) {
    res.json({"recipe name":"good recipe","recipe link":"www.goodrecipe.com"});
});

app.listen(3000);
```

I suspect there has to be something waiting for the response on a /search_result page from the way I have this set up, I just don't know what it is and what tools I should use next...

Answer (score 0):

You need to have express serve a page to parse that HTML on. Right now you are just telling it to send back a json object.

```
res.render('recipe.html');
```

You might want to look into options like `AngularJS` or using JQuery to send the request and have your front-end change on receiving a response.